# how to unhide numbers on the first column in the excel sheet

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet where the first column seems to be a running integer (excel sheet defined and not a user defined serial number), but sometimes it seems to miss a number or a bunch of numbers.

Why would this happen and how to avoid this? Note: We do excessive copying of rows and delete rows once in a while, but not sure why the running index is not being maintained by the excel sheet

Comment: belongs to http://superuser.com. voting to move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe as simple as hidden rows in your sheet. If so, then select the whole sheet (ctrl A) and then format->rows->unhide...

Comment: did try that, but it didn't seem to help

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the successive column which I am using is a user defined serial number which has the above formula. Not sure why this is affecting the first column which is excel defined

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of few rows of only those two columns? I am not sure if I am following now... I thought there were only one column affected :s